# TypeScript error inferring the correct type of user

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

```
import "./App.css";
import LoginPage from "./Components/LoginPage";
import HomePage from "./Components/HomePage.tsx";
import ProtectedRoute from "./Components/ProtectedRoute.tsx";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

interface User {
  name: string;
  phone: string;
  email: string;
}

function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    setUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")));
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={<ProtectedRoute isAuthenticated={user !== null} />}
        >
          <Route path="/home" element={<HomePage />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am getting an error during setState of user **Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string** I tried using interface for user but that does not work. Can you please help me identifying the issue here

Answer (score 0):

You need to narrow the type. Because you may or may not get a value local storage. You need to handle the possibility of getting a null value from your local storage.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) as User | null;
    if (user) setUser(user );
  }, []);
```